# how to put your text inside backquotes in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = "hello"
console.log(x)
//wanted output `hello` 
//Note i have no control on x i just need to put it inside the `` so that i can make a graphql query
```

I have a use case where I had a query I need to put that inside the backquotes so that i can make query using graphql.

I have written the query in a separate file because it was taking a lot of space making the code less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
let s="hello";
s="`"+s+"`";
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `\` before the back quotes like this

```
let string = "\`Hello\`";
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional solution to wrap any string with backticks using a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (note the backticks within the string are escaped):

```js
const x = "hello"

const wrapInBackTicks = (s) => `\`${s}\``

console.log(wrapInBackTicks(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let x = 'hello'
console.log('`'+x+'`')
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`

```js
let x = "hello"
console.log(JSON.stringify(x).replace(/"/g,"`"))
//wanted output `hello` 
//Note i have no control on x i just need to put it inside the `` so that i can make a graphql query
```